# Getting a black screen

Tags: swift, xcode

So, I am a begginer and I  have been following an online tutorial. I have copied the code and I get no errors but my program does not seem to be doeing anything. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Vision

class viewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo

    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else{ return }
    guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)else{ return }
    captureSession.addInput(input)

    captureSession.startRunning()


    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame

    let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self , queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
    captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)

   guard  let model  = try?VNCoreMLModel(for: SqueezeNet().model)else { return }
     let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model)
     {  (finishedReq, err) in

        //print(finishedReq.results)
        guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }

        guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }
        print (firstObservation.identifier, firstObservation.confidence)


    }
    //VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: <#T##CGImage#>, options: [:]).perform(requests: [VNRequest])


func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
     //print("Camera was able to capture a frame:", Date())
    guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)else { return }
   try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])

}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you forgot is asking permission to use the camera.

Something like:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video)
{ response in
    if response
    {
        // Access granted. You can continue.
    }
    else
    {
        // Tell the user.
    }
}
```

Also, you have the `AVCaptureSession` as a local/automatic variable. It will be deallocated leaving `viewDidLoad()`.  You must have is an instance variable.  The [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession) even shows this.

Having made at least above two simple mistakes, I advise you to follow a tutorial on how to do the basics. Then once you've got that right and you see something on screen, add the ML stuff.

Good luck, it seems like a very nice subject!